# Is it possible to override branch policy enforcement for specific files

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

We have branch policies set on our `develop` branch to require changes to be merged in from a completed pull request. Also, our build script automatically increments version numbers inside specific files and needs to push the updated files immediately, so in Branch Security we grant the user that runs that build script "Allow" for "Bypass policies when pushing". This is working fine.

However, bypassing the branch policy for the build user poses two potential problems:

1. If the build script were modified (either intentionally or not) to commit something other than version files, they would automatically get pushed to `develop` without any checks.
2. A rogue developer could use the build user's credentials to bypass the pull request policy and push out changes directly. (Perhaps this could be mitigated by changing the build user's password and not sharing it with developers.)

Is there a way to only allow a user to bypass the PR policy for specific files/folders in a push? If no, what other ways might there be to achieve this? (One hackish idea would be for the build script to automatically create a PR and have another user automatically parse it for only specific files and then complete it.)

<strike>We are currently on TFS on-premise 2015, but moving to TFS 2018 soon.</strike>  We are currently using Azure DevOps Server 2019 Update 1, though we can upgrade if newer versions have this feature (though I don't think they do).

Comment: Is there a specific reason why the version number needs to be stored in source control? Why not use a variable from the build to set the version number and then label the repository with the build identifier?

Comment: eg. 1.1.0.$(Build.BuildId)

Comment: @bryanbcook - off hand, other than "because it's always been done that way" I can't think of a good reason. I'm going to propose it.

Comment: yep, this is what we are doing. Powershell is used to make modifications to .csproj and other files on the build pipeline to increment the versions. Without doing this suggestion (which is the better way if it works for you), you could use negative path filters that allow your specific files to be excluded from the policy.

Comment: @JoshGust Could you elaborate on your negative path filters idea? I didn't know you could do that, but my initial thought is either it won't help because the other policies would still block the user from pushing without a PR, or, if that's not the case, then anyone would be able to push only those files without a PR, which also isn't desirable. My goal is to allow specific users to bypass a PR and push only a certain list of files.